# How to properly restart networking from a python script on a debian system?

Tags: python, networking, debian

I'm running a small debian (version 7.1) box that uses different wifi networks and works as a relay for images that I sent to it via my camera. Now sometimes it looses the connection to a network and if that happens I want to restart it's networking funictions just to make shure it's connecing properly.

In my early Linux days I learned to do `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. But apparently that doesn't work with WPASupplicant. So now I'm trying it with "wpa_action wlan0 restart;", but that still doesn't work. It seems to work from command line, but after using it like `os.system("wpa_action wlan0 restart;")` in python the box doesn't come back into the WIFI network.

So my question is:
What is the proper way to restart all network activity? How do I do it from my python script?

It's supposed to do everything that happens when I reboot the box, just without touching everything non-network related.

My WPA Supplicant config:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=0

network={
    id_str="home"
    ssid="xxx"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="xxx"
    priority=5
}

network={
        ssid="sender"
        scan_ssid=1
        psk="xxx"
        priority=9
}
```

My network interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
   wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface home inet dhcp
iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: Which version of Debian? My experience with Ubuntu is that the correct way to do these things has changed and is different almost from year to year.

Comment: It's debian 7.1! edit: Actually it's raspbian, but it shouldn't be too different.

Comment: Are `network-manager-gnome` or `network-manager-kde` installed? They are frontends to wpa supplicant and can sometimes cause headaches. If you're configuring wpa supplicant manually, it's best to kill these processes as they can cause strange things to happen.

Comment: Neither is installed. I just use command line on this one.

Answer (score 3):

To restart the interfaces your script will have to have adequate permissions (usually root).

```
import subprocess
my_cmd = "sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0"   # might be wlan0
proc = subprocess.Popen(my_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my raspberry pi's wifi to restart using the following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['sudo /sbin/ifdown wlan0 && sleep 10 && sudo /sbin/ifup --force wlan0'], shell=True)
```